# Manually added legend not working in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Here's facsimile of my data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
  e=rnorm(3000,10,10)
)
d2 <- data.frame(
  e=rnorm(2000,30,30)
)
```

So, I got around the problem of plotting two different density distributions from two very different datasets on the same graph by doing this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x=e),fill="red",data=d1) +
  geom_density(aes(x=e),fill="blue",data=d2)
```

But when I try to manually add a legend, like so:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x=e),fill="red",data=d1) +
  geom_density(aes(x=e),fill="blue",data=d2) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Data", values = c("XXXXX" = "red","YYYYY" = "blue"))
```

Nothing happens.  Does anybody know what's going wrong?  I thought I could actually manually add legends if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Generally ggplot works best when your data is in a single `data.frame` and in long format. In your case we therefore want to combine the data from both `data.frame`s. For this simple example, we just concatenate the data into a long variable called `d` and use an additional column `id` to indicate to which dataset that value belongs.

```
d.f <- data.frame(id = rep(c("XXXXX", "YYYYY"), c(3000, 2000)), 
                  d = c(d1$e, d2$e))
```

More complex data manipulations can be done using packages such as `reshape2` and `tidyr`. I find [this cheat sheet](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) often useful. Then when we plot we map `fill` to `id`, and ggplot will take of the legend automatically.

```
ggplot(d.f, aes(x = d, fill = id)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: The legend is created when you "map" a variable from the data frame onto an aesthetic like `color` or `fill`. Imagine that your two data frames are stacked vertically (i.e. "long" format), and there is an additional column specifying which group the numbers came from. That grouping variable is what you'd map to the aesthetic.

Comment: Added a bit more explanation.